# Изменить класс загрузки с MainActivity на другой, как?

Tags: android, firebase

У меня есть приложение, хочу прикрутить регистрацию с помощью Firebase. Написал отдельный класс, но не знаю как указать что б он грузился первым, вместо MainActivity, а MainActivity  открывался при успешном входе (это я знаю как).
Как изменить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Какую активити запускать при старте приложения система определяет по интент-фильтру. В манифесте главная активити выглядит так:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activity.LicenceActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Т.е. перенесите

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

внутрь тега новой главной активити.

---

В этой новой главной активити при старте, в onCreate проверяйте что юзер авторизован и запускайте следующую активити, завершив эту либо показывайте ему кнопки для авторизации с последующим перенаправлением дальше